# NSFetchedResultsController and WebService

Tags: ios, web-services, core-data

I will be using core data as a local cache for a web service. While fetching data, I want to first check if data exists in core data , if it does, then show it(and save the network call) , but if it does not ,request the web service for it, and also add to core data.

NSFetchedResults controller, out of the box  , directly talks to core data. 
Is it possible for it to do this kind of check ?

I have a set of data entities that will either be synced, or unsynced( i plan to store the sync/unsync flag in nsuserdefaults).
When the view is loaded,say list view, if the flag is synced, then web request will not be required.

If that flag is false, then web service should be called.

Answer (score 1):

`NSFetchedResultsController` won't do this. It only talks to Core Data, and there's no option to have it automatically do extra checks. You'll have to do the checks somewhere else, and call your web service from there.

Comment: where can I do that check?
Say I have a long list. As I scroll up , I think nsfetched results controller will batch pull core data rows into an array . But say there were no more rows left. This is where I want to talk to web service to add more rows to core data (and then I think nsfetchedresultscontroller is notified of updates)